# Привязка списка <select> к данным в таблице

Tags: php, mysqli

Всем привет. Уже очень долго пытаюсь решить этот вопрос. Идея такова: хотел сделать админ панель с выпадающим списком `<select>` и привязкой его пунктов к `id` в таблице `mysqli`. [image: Админ панель]

Соответственно для запроса `UPDATE` к таблице нужны переменные, которые я не могу назначить.

```
UPDATE `magazin` SET `price`='переменная1' WHERE id='переменная2'
```

Comment: а интерфейс у вас на чем? html? и в чем именно сложность?

Comment: Да html, сложность в том, что у меня не получается связать данные из списка с таблицей.

Comment: мне бы узнать как пункты селект заключить в переменную, чтоб их в запрос можно было вставить.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно получить данные с формы и их использовать для запроса в БД

Пример формы:

```html
<form action="save.php" method="post">
  <select name="photoID">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose photo</option>
    <option value="1"># 1</option>
    <option value="2"># 2</option>
    <option value="3"># 3</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save options">
</form>
```

Код `save.php` будет содержать примерно такой код:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['photoID'])){
    $photoID = intval($_POST['photoID']);
    if($photoID){
       echo "You photo ID: ".$photoID; 
    } else {
        echo "Wrong photo ID";
    }
}
```